# Planck time, time or time interval?

Tags: time, physical-constants, discrete, absolute-units

[Planck time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) is really a weird topic, if we try to find out that is it time or time interval. 
It is the time taken by light to travel a Planck LENGTH so it must be time interval. But we also know that Planck length is MOST FUNDAMENTAL and it can't be differentiated anymore. So what's the reality?

Comment: The premises of this question are false. See [this old question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76515/planck-time-length).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is time continuous?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/)