# What is the shortest controllable time?

Tags: time, measurements

I was reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time and noticed a reference to: http://phys.org/news192909576.html where it is stated that:

**12 attoseconds is the world record for shortest controllable time**

This article is now almost 4 years old, is this still the record or is in the meantime this record broken?

Comment: I asked a very similar question here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89975/

Comment: @BrandonEnright Both interesting questions. Is it right to assume that you're also interested in theory about the shortest timespan that *may be* measured, whereas this question is exclusively about empirical observation of short durations? (So the questions aren't duplicates.)

Comment: @BlackbodyBlacklight I don't think they're duplicates.  Just related.  I'm interested in the theoretical / experimental upper bound if time were discrete.

Comment: I think the quantum time limits (e.g. the Margolus–Levitin theorem) might imply that the shortest controllable time will be dependent on the energy of the system doing the controlling. But a lot hinges on how we define control here. Causing a desired state transition?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we reached zeptosecond controllable time in 2021:

Using transient magnons, Physicists have tuned the quantum phase of a quantum system embedded in a solid with a precision of 1 zs and a timing stability below 50 ys. [1]

[1] : https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abc3991 (Bocklage et al., Science Advances, Vol 7 Issue 5, 28 Jan 2021)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon here.  Can you please edit your answer to include the important details from the article, so that this answer stands on its own?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert done