# Discrete time like a computer program

Tags: time, discrete

Has anybody thought about the effects of discretizing time in the way most computers do? In computer programming; collision detection for example, or updating a trajectory of a particle, everything is done by necessity in frames vs continuously. What I've read about quantum time has to do with restricting intervals to some smallest length, which is fundamentally different. In one way the universe would be updated an infinite number of times from time $a$ to time $b$ though time $a$ to $b$ is an extremely small amount... and then what the universe just sort of shuts off? blinks out?

From what I've read the point of quantizing time is to make renormalization possible which has to do with getting rid of infinite quantities, maybe those infinite quantities would get out of the way even easier if we used the other way of quantization (time isn't intervals it's instances in which the universe blinks into existence and calculates a bunch of finite trajectories then blinks out to move everything to those trajectory calculated locations).

As further specification of this concept and it's consequences, you could check out the program and the discussion on the help request tab below it, which inspired this question. http://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-the-singularity/5538557195976704

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89975/2451 and links therein.

Comment: not 100% sure of your question, esp. when you ask _point of quantizing time is to make renormalization possible_, in effect are you asking is spacetime discrete?

Comment: Essentially every practical clock discretizes time measurement, but discretization has absolutely nothing to do with quantization.