# Is the time-energy uncertainty relation affected by the refractive index of materials?

Tags: particle-physics, refraction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

For the time-energy uncertainty relation, is it or is it possible it could be affected by the refractive index of a material?  In other words, if you have a material where the speed of light passing through is slower than in the vacuum, would that affect c^2 in the energy portion of the relation and reduce the energy thus allowing for the time or mass of virtual particles to be higher?

Comment: Explicitly what uncertainty relation are you talking about?  In particular how does $c^2$ enter in this?

Comment: Delta(E)*Delta(t)>=h/4pi

Comment: Pray explain how $c^2$ enters in this?  We’re talking about energy of a state, not of a particle... (see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365873/36194)