# Does anything exist in between a particular time period?

Tags: spacetime, time, universe, discrete

I don't think I can further elaborate this. It's pretty straight forward.
If we know something (say a **tortoise**) to exist at two points in time, then can we rightfully assume that it has existed everywhere in between that time period?                      Or let's say you open a box and find a cat in it. Then you close it, and after some time open it and find the cat still there. So, can you rightfully assume the cat to be in box, while it was closed?

Comment: What do you mean by "existed"?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/2451 and links therein.

Comment: the two point events in time that you use to define an interval are arbitrary, why would these two points be special?

Comment: Biophysist 14. I can give an example.             Let's say I open a box and a ball is in it, and then close it for some time, then reopen it and find the ball still there. Now, can I assume the ball was in the box all the time, the box was closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can rightfully assume, that it existed in between, Thats what we assume in all physical laws. But be sure it is an assumption, which nobody rally can prove.

Comment: Hey that was great help. I feel like I can ask the entire question now. If now let's say this tortoise has no way existed in between the time period, at what's ends it was found. So, can we again rightfully assume that there wasn't any time between the end points, so not existing in that part isn't a problem anymore.        So, simply I mean to ask, in that case, is time really quantized?

Comment: why should the time period between the two occurrence of your tortoise not exist? you just did not observe it, so you don't know if it existed or not, but the time existed . how else could you "observe at two times.

Comment: I mean if even time isn't existing in the moment, then there's no point in discussion the existence of the tortoise.

Comment: Actually never mind. It's really hard to actually ask the question what I'm meaning to ask. The above questions are a part of another question. Why can't time be quantized.