# What is the cardinality of time?

Tags: spacetime, time

Since there must be a domain for time, and every domain we can estimate its cardinality.

Are we having a countable many of time or an uncountable many of time?

Sorry for confusing two different concepts set cardinality and time together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is time continuous or discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/)

Comment: I did run into that question first, but I don't think it would cover my question, as continuous or discrete is a very rough estimate of set property which would depend on the topology. While cardinality is the property of the domain itself.

Comment: That's true, but the answer to the linked question explains that we don't know about continuity vs discreteness, which implies that we also don't the cardinality.

Comment: interesting... then there must be some previous attempt at understanding them?

Comment: We have *no* experimental evidence that time is not continuous, like the real numbers. In all widely accepted theories, a temporal coordinate *is* a real number.