# Is nature discretizable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, hamiltonian, dirac-delta-distributions, discrete

From mathematical perspective, can we describe all the realistic quantum mechanical phenomena at any given moment by functions alone, or is it correct that distributional behavior can also be observed at an experiment?
For example, the "Dirac comb potential", given by:
$$H(t)=\sum_{k}\delta(t-kT)$$
cannot be discretized. Can such a behavior be also observed experimentally?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/2451