# Planck time - what would I see?

Tags: cosmology, time, universe, discrete

Impossibly hypothetical, but to communicate the question: when the universe "ticks" a plank second, what does a particle do? I'd imagine the natural conception that it moves from position a to position b instantly, like a frame in a movie, is wrong. If I were "watching" the particle at the time, what would I "see"? What happens?

Explain it to me like I dropped out end of second year physics bachelors :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is time continuous or discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/)

Comment: Hi Rabbi :-) See the question I have linked above. Time is not discrete. The Planck time is not the shortest time, it's just the shortest _time interval_ that could be measured. So the universe does not _tick_ in Planck times.

Comment: thanks @JohnRennie very helpful