# Experiments to resolve dillema between continuity and discrete

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, universe, computational-physics, theory-of-everything

Which experiments/experimental methods are suggested to resolve an alternative about the structure of our universe space and time - is it continuous or is it discrete in a very small scale, especially regarding when proved equations could break in case of discrete structure?

related: [Is the universe finite and discrete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/is-the-universe-finite-and-discrete)

Comment: Conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: Unexpectedly,my sense is that most qm physicists don't feel comfortable with this aspect...